# Using find_by_sql in range gives error: undefined method `value_for_database' for "2017-01-01":String

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This error showed up when I was trying to search from a range of date.

This is my model:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    @policies = Policy.find_by_sql("acct_ent_date IN ?", start_date..end_date)
  else
    limit(10)
  end
end
```

Comment: What query you are getting on compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rarely need to drop down to writing raw SQL in rails (e.g. using the `find_by_sql` method) - especially for such a simple query as this.

Instead, you can just write the following and `ActiveRecord` will correctly convert it to valid SQL syntax for you:

```
# If you are looking for a list of all matching entries:
Policy.where(acct_ent_date: start_date..end_date)


# If you only wish to fetch the FIRST matching entry:
Policy.find_by(acct_ent_date: start_date..end_date)
```

This will generate SQL like the following:

```
SELECT `policies`.* FROM `policies` WHERE (`policies`.`acct_ent_date` BETWEEN xxxxx AND yyyyy)
```

The key problem with your original (raw SQL) code is that you are using `WHERE IN` syntax - which is really just [shorthand](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php) for multiple OR conditions. This does not make sense to use with a **`Range`** (`start_date..end_date`) object, as this is not a discrete list (i.e. an `Array`).

If you were to attempt to convert your object into an array, you would see an error something like this:

```
(start_date..end_date).to_a # => TypeError: can't iterate from Time
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to help out anyone else coming here: If you want to use query params with `find_by_sql`, you need to put *all the arguments* into an array, like this:

```
Policy.find_by_sql(["acct_ent_date IN ?", start_date..end_date])
```

I've never actually seen passing a range as a query parameter, so I can't comment on that, but in general the "undefined method `value_for_database'" error comes from not wrapping the arguments in an array.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question.